# Rolling sum with shifted index in pandas

Tags: pandas

Given the following data frame

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, -9]})
df = df['col1'].rolling(3).mean()
```

However, I want a shifted rolling horizon that gives me the mean of each row with index i as the average of index i-4, i-5, and i-6.

x_i = (x_{i-4} + x_{i-5} + x_{i-6})/3

Is there a way to do it with shift and rolling?

Desired output
NAN, NAN, NAN, NAN, NAN, NAN, (1+2+3)/3, (2+3+4)/3

Comment: df['col1'].iloc[::-1] seems to inverse the dataframe. I just want to shift them by -6 and then take the average of rolling(3).

Comment: either `df['col1'].rolling(3).mean().shift(4)` or `df.col1.shift(4).rolling(3).mean()`, the `4` comes from `i-4` in your request.

Comment: This also does not work. I added desired output

Comment: This looks correct: df.col1.shift(4).rolling(3).mean()